# how to debug nodejs project in visual studio 2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

i want to run my project in visual studio  in command prompt its working fine, how do this please help me, i want to debug code in visual studio, i was install nodejs tool for visual studio, please check below images

```
"main": "src/app.js",
```

[i want run in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66193.jpg)

[in command line its working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqSRG.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to run the node.js application from inside Visual Studio, in debug mode?

Comment: yes but its not working